# How to use while loop to ask for response until a correct response is given

Tags: java, calculator

I am creating a calculator to calculate the number of points you get based on your grade but i want to make a while loop such that if the response is not an actual grade, the code will keep asking till an actual grade is given. but when I add the while loop, the scanner does not seem to scan the input at all? (quite new to java, tried to implement the answers from similar questions but still doesn't work)

```java
double firsth2 = 0;
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("What did you get for your highest scoring H2 subject?");
String firstgrade = scanner.next();
while (!(firstgrade.equalsIgnoreCase("A") && firstgrade.equalsIgnoreCase("B") && firstgrade.equalsIgnoreCase("C") && firstgrade.equalsIgnoreCase("D") && firstgrade.equalsIgnoreCase("E") && firstgrade.equalsIgnoreCase("S") && firstgrade.equalsIgnoreCase("U"))) {
    System.out.println("Please enter a real grade");
      scanner.reset();
    firstgrade= scanner.next();
}

switch (firstgrade) {
    case "A", "a" -> firsth2 = 20;
    case "B", "b" -> firsth2 = 17.5;
    case "C", "c" -> firsth2 = 15;
    case "D", "d" -> firsth2 = 12.5;
    case "E", "e" -> firsth2 = 10;
    case "S", "s" -> firsth2 = 5;
    case "U", "u" -> firsth2 = 0;
}
```

Comment: `firstgrade.equalsIgnoreCase("A") && firstgrade.equalsIgnoreCase("B")` can never be true

Comment: I think you wanted to use `||` instead of `&&` inside your while condition

Comment: @TomCarmi omg thanku! i changed it and it works! but do u mind explaining why && is wrong? i'm not sure why because i thought i needed to use && to make sure that the input isn't equal to all the conditions

Comment: && is used to check if all conditions are satisfied but || will check if any of the condition is satisfied

Comment: @VenkateshTalacheeru but if i use || and my input is for example "A", it doesn't satisfy !equalsIgnoreCase("A") so why would the loop still break?

Comment: @Kaylene, you want to check that `firstgrade` does not equal any of the grades. 
so it does not (`!`) equal "A" or "B" or "C"....
what you were checking it does not equal both "A" and "B" and "C"...
It can not equal them all at once, so it will always give true (with the `!`)

Comment: BTW, a much more readable way would be to put all the grades in a list and check in the condition that `while (!listOfGrades.contains(firstgrade)) {`....

Comment: @TomCarmi ohh ok understood, thank you! will def make a list to make the code neater

Answer (score 1):

You could do it this way:

```
final Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
final String ls = System.lineSeparator();
double firstH2 = 0d;
            
String firstGrade = "";
while (firstGrade.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.print("What did you get for your highest scoring H2 subject?" 
                   + ls + "Enter Grade: A, B, C, D, E, S, U, or Q to exit: -> ");
    firstGrade = userInput.nextLine();
    switch (firstGrade.toUpperCase()) {
        case "A": firstH2 = 20; break;
        case "B": firstH2 = 17.5; break;
        case "C": firstH2 = 15; break;
        case "D": firstH2 = 12.5; break;
        case "E": firstH2 = 10; break;
        case "Q": 
            System.out.println("Quiting - Bye Bye");
            return;
        case "S": firstH2 = 5; break;
        case "U": firstH2 = 0; break;
        default: {
            System.out.println("Invalid Grade (" + firstGrade + ") Supplied! Try again..." + ls);
            firstGrade = "";
        }
    }
}
   
System.out.println(firstH2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `scanner.nextLine` instead of `scanner.next`